# php memcached stats page, using PECL::memcache

Tags: php, memcached, pecl, libm

I'm running php 5.3. I have installed the pecl memcache extension. Once upon a time there was the memcache.php (which I'm aware is still around and usable) for viewing useful memcached stats and other info. At some point this page was committed into the pecl memcached extension (can't get the link to the commit atm).

My question is once the extension is installed how do I view this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view the result of the `memcache.php` file, you'll have to :

- download it *(download the `.tgz` archive from [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache), it should be included)*
- Eventually, configure the `memcache.php` file, to indicate which servers should be monitored

  - You'll have to configure the `$MEMCACHE_SERVERS` array
- Put that `memcache.php` file somewhere on your server

  - Making sure it's somewhere that's not publicly accessible.
- Access the file from your browser ;-)

Installing the PECL memcache extension will allow you to use communicate with a memcached server from PHP -- but it'll not install the `memcache.php` file on your webserver.

Apparently, this file has been added in PECL for these two versions of the extension :

- [3.0.2](http://pecl.php.net/package-info.php?package=memcache&version=3.0.2)
- and [2.2.4](http://pecl.php.net/package-info.php?package=memcache&version=2.2.4)

Comment: Am I correct in assuming the memcache.php file is installed when installing the pecl extension, in my case via `apt-get` ?

Comment: It turns out I was correct, I just had to symlink the file to a web directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Telnet to connect to the memcached IP address and port and use certain commands to get stats. [Here's an article that might help.](http://www.itecsoftware.com/web-development/testing-memcached-using-telnet-commands)

Answer (score 0):

The file you needed is here: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/memcache/trunk/memcache.php?view=markup

Comment: I'm aware of what the file is, and where to find it. My question is, since the 3.0.2 version of memcached, I was under the impression that the memcache.php was installed when the pecl extension was installed, in my case via `apt-get`. I want to know if this is infact the case, how do I access the file via the browser?